# How to change alpha value of all material in a single go?

Tags: materials, transparency, blend-files

I have a blend file in which all the materials alpha value is 0.
There are too many materials for me to change the alpha value manually to 1.
Is there a way I can change alpha valuec of all materials in a single go??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this script

```py
import bpy
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if not mat.use_nodes: continue
    for n in mat.node_tree.nodes:
        if n.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
            n.inputs["Alpha"].default_value = 1
```

Comment: thanks you saved my lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Based on top suggestion i made this script:

```
import bpy
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if not mat.use_nodes: continue
    if mat.blend_method == "BLEND":
        mat.blend_method = "HASHED"
```

it works on blender 3.1